# Is it expensive to continuously dealloc and alloc in Objective C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have an iPhone app that has a 4 option menu, and allows the user to switch between view controllers quickly. So I thought to make the experience smoother, every time the user switches between view controllers, the `from` view controller is released right away, and the `to` allocated. And the user will most likely be doing a lot of switching. Is there a better way to handle memory here than to keep releasing and allocating the same view controllers over and over again?

Comment: Does quickly mean pushing?  Because the first Views on the navigation stack aren't  released if they're pushed

Comment: No it doesn't use a navigation controller. Just a custom CommonViewController that switches between 4 View Controllers and releases the `from` and allocates the `to` every time..

Comment: If you are worried about memory, why not just use a navigation controller then hide it?  Even presenting modal views would be more efficient.

Comment: What does instruments tell you?  Does it show huge CPU costs to perform what you're doing?  Keep in mind that mobile devices have limited resources and it is probably better to limit the amount of memory you're using rather than limit the CPU usage.

Comment: Why what's the difference between modal views and what I'm doing? And what's the difference between limiting memory and limited CPU?

Comment: The difference is that not only is it easier to manage the views, but it provides the user a common way to get back to the first view (if it really is as common as you say), it also manages the releasing of views for you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

View controllers aren't expensive. It is ok to alloc and release them. However the views can be expensive. When memory is low, the system tries to unload the views of the view controllers which are currently not visible. Your app should always be aware of that. Release expensive objects in viewDidUnload, i.e. IBOutlets and data that can be recreated.

If you experience performance issues you should hold all 4 view controllers in memory. So the views will be loaded faster. iOS takes care of unloading the not visible views (when appropriate).

Answer (score 1):

If it's the user doing the switching, time spent in dealloc and/or alloc is completely insignificant, bar any extremely time-consuming operations like loading tens/hundreds of images, etc.

In short, both an on-demand and a cached solution will have some tiny advantage over the other. Your users will not notice the difference though.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you might have been better off with a tab bar app?

If memory is your main concern then it sounds like you will be loading and unloading a lot which will be a slower experience for the end-user.

If you use a tab bar controller then the views in unused tabs will be automagically unloaded if memory is needed. and loaded again if/when necessary.